# Merge 2 object arrays in json files by key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm trying to combine 2 object array in javascript/jquery matching them by the same key (code). These object arrays are stored in 2 separate json files.

I've cut these down as the files are long

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Object 1:

```
[{
    "city": "london",
    "selfemployed": {
        "job" :"Builder",
        "code": "abc"
    },
    "company" : {
        "job": "Shopkeeper",
        "code": "def"
    }
}]
```

Object 2:

```
[{
    "code": "abc",
    "participant": {
        "firstname" : "Joe",
        "lastname" : "Blogs"
    }
},
{
    "code": "def",
    "participant": {
        "firstname" : "Anna",
        "lastname" : "Smith"
    }
}]
```

Needed result:

```
[{
    "city": "london",
    "selfemployed": {
        "job" :"Builder",
        "code": "abc",
        "participant": {
            "firstname" : "Joe",
            "lastname" : "Blogs"
        }
    },
    "company" : {
        "job": "Shopkeeper",
        "code": "def",
        "participant": {
            "firstname" : "Anna",
            "lastname" : "Smith"
        }
    }
}]
```

One of my issues is that I'm unable to return the object from the .json files

```
var file1 = 'url/file1.json';
var file1 = 'url/file2.json';

const joinJson = (file1, file2) => {
    $.getJSON(file, function(data1) {
        return data1;

    });

    $.getJSON(file2, function(data2) {
        return data2;

    });

    // do stuff with data1 and data2
}
console.log(joinJson());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and build new objects for the result by selecting the wanted code information for the new object.

This proposal uses rest properties of an object with babel for older user agents.

```js
var cities = [{ city: "london", selfemployed: { job: "Builder", code: "abc" }, company: { job: "Shopkeeper", code: "def" } }],
    codes = [{ code: "abc", participant: { firstname: "Joe", lastname: "Blogs" } }, { code: "def", participant: { firstname: "Anna", lastname: "Smith" } }],
    codesMap = new Map(codes.map(({ code, participant }) => [code, participant])),
    result = cities.map(
        ({ city, ...items }) =>
            Object.assign({ city }, ...Object.entries(items).map(
                ([k, v]) => ({ [k]: Object.assign({}, v, codesMap.get(v.code)) })
            ))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. How would I go about this if both objects are in .json files?

Comment: you need two async methods to read the files and then join them. maybe the other answer could help you about that part.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're getting the files asynchronously, and returning data in the callback of that async operation, which goes nowhere. Something like this would be better:

```
var file1 = 'url/file1.json';
var file1 = 'url/file2.json';

const joinJson = (file1, file2) => {
    $.getJSON(file, function(data1) {
        // async operation 1 complete. Start operation 2.
        $.getJSON(file2, function(data2) {
            // async operation 2 complete
            // data1 and data2 are now available here
            console.log("Data 1:", data1);
            console.log("Data 2:", data2);

            // This will merge the keys of both objects
            // but you can replace it with custom merging logic
            var merged = Object.assign(data1, data2);
            console.log(merged);
        });
    });   
}
```

The problem here is that you can't do something like `console.log(joinJson());`. You may very well need something like a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).